# MVC Music Store Tutorial in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, store

I am following the MVC 3 Music Store Tutorial for MVC in MVC 4 and have got stuck on page 28 (page 29 in the PDF). I have added my first view as instructed but when I look at my solution folders I do not have one called Views/Shared with _Layout.cshtml listed under it which the tutorial clearly shows in the sample screens. I have searched the solution for _Layout.cshtml and it does not appear to be there. This means that I am now stuck and can't progress with learning MVC 4 as I would like.

I have tried finding help on the Web and on YouTube but the best I can come up with is to "read the Release Notes". As MVC is new to me (I have spent the last 40 years developing in RDMS type environments) the release notes don't mean as much to me as they might in the future and are not helping.

With my lack of experience with MVC I don't know if I have simply missed something simple or am trying to do something that is no longer supported in MVC 4.

I am hoping that someone with more knowledge and experience than I, has produced notes on how to run the MVC Music Store Tutorial in MVC 4. I don't mind draft notes as long as I can get going again learning this new way (to me) of developing serious applications.

I look forward to a reply.

Comment: Did you download the source code for the Music Store or are you coding along from scratch?

Comment: Did you use a blank MVC project template or an internet application template?

Comment: Brett, thanks for taking time to respond. I did downlioad the source code but was coding from scratch. After much head scratching and trial and error I have managed to resolve my problem and I am moving on with the tutorial. The solution was to create the project using a Basic template instead of an Empty one as shown in the tutorial. When I did that the Shared folder appeared and when I created the first View it added _Layout.cshtml as explained in the tutorial. This means that I can carry on with the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to create the project using a Basic template instead of an Empty one as shown in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Next time you encounter an issue like that, just right click the solution name, then "add" folder, in this case call it shared, then right click the shared folder to add whatever files you need. 
I struggled a bit with a similar issue as well.